# Creating transparent PNG images in PHP with GD leaves fuzzy edges

Tags: php, png, gd, alpha-transparency

I have a transparent logo in a png file. I'm trying to create a transparent box image which would be the background for the logo. So the final image would be a merge of the programmatically-created, transparent png and the transparent logo from the file.  The code that I'm using works, however the results show the logo with fuzzy black edges. Any ideas on how to get a sharper image?

Here is my code:

```
$source=imagecreatefrompng($logoFile);
imagealphablending($source, false);
imagesavealpha($source, true);   
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor(450,280);
$black = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($newImage, $black);
imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,$x,$y,450,280,$width,$height);
imagepng($newImage,$imageDirectory,0); 
imagedestroy($newImage);
```

**Edited**
Sorry, I guess I should've been more clear. The image file that is coming in is from a file upload form field. And most of the files are organization logos. Some of the .png files include a transparency alpha channel(they're not completely transparent). The reason that I have to recreate it is because I'm also using [cropper.js](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/), which is a tool that lets you zoom in or crop the file being uploaded, and I need the final file to be 450x280 regardless of how big or small the file uploaded was. So in my code, `$x, $y, $width, $height` are sent by cropper.js after the user has manipulated the original image.

As I said, the image manipulation is working correctly. The only problem is that when I user submits a png with transparency, the logo is real fuzzy, with black edges. When I change black to another color in `$black = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 0, 0, 0);` I loose all of the transparency.

Here is a sample input and output file. The one on the left is the original image, the one on the right is the output. The output of this test image isn't as bad as real images. There's way more fuzziness on real images.

[image]

Comment: An example input and output file would probably be useful.

Comment: Also, try `imagecopy()` rather than `imagecopyresampled()` seeing as you're not resizing anything there's no need to resample it, and I could see that causing fuzziness.

Comment: what is a transparent logo? I have never heard of a transparent logo. well if it's transparent, it's nothing in alpha channel.

Comment: If you change `$black` to something else, do you still get "fuzzy *black* edges"? Or, if you change it to purple, do you get 'fuzzy purple edges'?

Comment: @Sammitch I tried using `imagecopy()` but I still got the same results.

Comment: @Wils Sorry, I wasn't aware I was dealing with 2nd graders. The logo isn't fully transparent; parts of it are transparent as it has an alpha channel. Funny, how everyone else new what I meant.

Comment: @usr2564301 If I change black to any other color the background is no longer transparent. Thanx

Comment: FYI: the first part that second-last comment is the precise moment you decided your question wasn't going to get answered.

Comment: I found the problem. First off I tried to use `imagecopymerge` to see if I got a better result. I read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) and Rodrigo's post on it really helped out. I tried to use his function but then the entire transparency was gone. That's when I realized that my server's GD version is preventing `imagecreatetruecolor` from working correctly. No matter what color I use I always end up with black. I updated GD and everything looks way better.

Comment: FYI: @Sammitch Thanx for your help and advise. But I thought these forums were for people trying to learn or teach others. What's the point of coming here just to be a "Grammar Police". If someone doesn't have something productive or helpful to post why come on here just to be a smart ass? And I don't mean you, I mean the other person. 
Once again, thanx!!

Comment: Can someone please explain why my "question" is getting downvoted? Several other people have asked similar questions when they couldn't get any transparency at all. My problem was that ,although I was getting transparency, I was getting fuzziness around the edges of characters or images. It would help out to know why my "question" is not up to par?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. First off I tried to use imagecopymerge to see if I got a better result. I read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) and Rodrigo's post on it really helped out. I tried to use his function but then the entire transparency was gone. That's when I realized that my server's GD version is preventing imagecreatetruecolor from working correctly. No matter what color I use I always end up with black. I updated GD and everything looks way better.